# Untranslocated Node : FileManager error on iPadOS running on MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I'm building an app that will allow users to provision it with multiple videos. Because this app has to run in environments without internet available at all times, I'd like to be able to load these videos by putting them into the app's directory, and then importing them as binary objects managed by CoreData.

However, it also needs to be able to run on Silicon Macs, and so far, so good. All the app functionality is identical on both platforms.

But when I try to access the .documentDirectory for the .userDomainMask while it's running on MacOS, I get the error

```
LSPrefs: could not find untranslocated node for <FSNode 0x600003b02a80> { isDir = ?, path = '/private/var/folders/6v/58try04d2kb4vm02q5gz6qq00000gn/X/C485B932-6696-587A-BCE6-BF4501414ACE/d/Wrapper/VideoMentor.app' }, proceeding on the assumption it is not translocated: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
```

is this because there's no concept of a .userDomainMask, when iOS runs on MacOS? and I should go another route? What is an untranslocated node?

Comment: Here's an article explaining what translocation is. I don't think it answers your question, but it is probably good background knowledge https://eclecticlight.co/2021/04/19/ios-apps-are-translocated-when-run-in-macos/